# Having trouble replicating Access Query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ms-access, pivot, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is the Access Query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(EMPL_VAL_AMT) AS SumOfEMPL_VAL_AMT
SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, 
ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, 
EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, 
ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD
FROM EMPL_FCST
GROUP BY ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, 
ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, 
EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, 
ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD
ORDER BY FDATE([EMPL_FMONTH] & "/" & [EMPL_FYEAR])
PIVOT FDATE([EMPL_FMONTH] & "/" & [EMPL_FYEAR]);
```

Here is my attempt at it in Oracle 12cr2:

```
SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD
FROM EMPL_FCST
GROUP BY ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD
ORDER BY EMPL_FMONTH || "/" || EMPL_FYEAR AS FDATE
PIVOT
(
  SUM(EMPL_VAL_AMT) IN EMPL_FMONTH || "/" || EMPL_FYEAR AS FDATE
)
```

I am trying to create a pivot that combines two fields `EMPL_FMONTH` and `EMPLY_FYEAR` as `FDATE` to be the column heading for a sum of `EMP_VAL_AMT`. Bascially have `1/18 | 2/18 | 3/18` across the top with the sum of `EMPL_VAL_AMT` under each time period.

Here is the error I got trying to run the code:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD
FROM EMPL_FCST
GROUP BY ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD
ORDER BY EMPL_FMONTH || "/" || EMPL_FYEAR AS FDATE
PIVOT
(
  SUM(EMPL_VAL_AMT) IN EMPL_FMONTH || "/" || EMPL_FYEAR AS FDATE
)
Error at Command Line : 4 Column : 43
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have been trying various combinations of brackets, parenthesis, and ordering to clean up the syntax. Beyond that I'm not even sure if I'm approaching the logic correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Okay I rewrote the query using everyone's feedback to this and it ran successfully:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ORG_TOT_LOWEST_LEVEL_ID, ORG_TOT_ACCTG_DEPT_ID, 
EMPL_SCENR_DIM_MBR_CD, EMPL_VER_DIM_MBR_CD, ORG_TOT_ALLOC_POOL_CD, 
EMPL_VAL_AMT, EMPL_FMONTH, EMPL_FYEAR
FROM EMPL_FCST
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(EMPL_VAL_AMT) 
  FOR EMPL_FYEAR 
  IN (2018, 2019)
)
```

Is there a way to combine the `FYEAR` column and the `FMONTH` column into one column that looks like MM/YYYY and then use that as my FOR in the pivot clause?

Comment: Quite confused here. You have this tagged with sql server and the question title says sql server. But your code and your error message is oracle. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi sorry I am using Oracle. I am a noob.

Comment: No problem mate. We will get you squared away. :)

Comment: O thank you. That makes a lot more sense. Does SQL mean MySQL server?

Comment: Ditch the GROUP BY clause (why are you using a GROUP BY anyway, no need/no added value) and try again.

Comment: No. MySql, Sql Server and Oracle are all examples of different database systems. Just like Chevrolet, Honda and Ford are different types of vehicles. They each come with their own syntax oddities but basically all do the same thing.

Comment: I rewrote the query using everyone's feedback. Please see my edit.